# java intellij nullpointerexception form, not firing constructor

Tags: java, forms, intellij-idea, constructor, nullpointerexception

I am beginner with Java and come across an issue. Hopefully I will get some tips here. I work with **Intellij IDEA 15.0 community edition**
I am trying to create a form, really simple one, 2x JTextField for now.
I have created test project to help you understand my query.

Main.java(here is where we start)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject ob = new MyObject();
        System.out.println("MyObject: "+ob.testInteger);
        JFrame wrapper = new JFrame("Intellij Test");
        MyWindow myWindow = new MyWindow(ob);
        wrapper.setContentPane(myWindow);
        wrapper.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        wrapper.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

MyObject.java

```
public class MyObject {
    public int testInteger;
    public MyObject() {
        testInteger = 120;
    }
}
```

MyWindow.java

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    private JTextField myTextField;
    private JPanel myWindowPanel;

    private MyObject mob;
    public MyWindow(MyObject ob) {
        System.out.println("This code should ran first???");
        this.mob = ob;
        myTextField = new JTextField();
    }


    private void createUIComponents() {
        System.out.println("But this one is ran instead");
        String test = ""+mob.testInteger;
        myTextField.setText("MyObject value is: "+test);
    }
}
```

My Form is just plain JPanel with one JTextField done in graphical form generator with names applied and Custom Create ticked for both myTextField and myWindowPanel.

Here is the output:

```
MyObject: 120
But this one is ran instead
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyWindow.createUIComponents(MyWindow.java:27)
    at MyWindow.$$$setupUI$$$(MyWindow.java)
    at MyWindow.<init>(MyWindow.java:19)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This creates a big problem for my beginner skills, as I have no idea how else can I pass object to my GUI so I have data to fill JTextFields with.

This is my first OO programming attempt so hopefully I can get some interesting advise here.

Thanks,
Maciej

Comment: some specific question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious. I need to pass an Object to MyWindow.class. When I do it with Constructor it returns NullPointerException as Constructor is ran after other GUI constructing methods. How do I get my object through and use it correctly?

Comment: I am not sure if this is related to exact same problem, but here
https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/268051
This suppoused to be fixed (so constructor is being processed before createUIComponents) years ago...

Comment: You can ignore me, I have misunderstood reasoning behind createUIComponents method and its purpose. I can move content dependent code to Constructor leaving only initialization of Swing Elements (or those extending Swing) in createUICompontents and it works fine.

I am really surprised though there is some other method running before constructor and I don't really understand that. So since I have already asked the question, maybe somebody would be kind enough and explain how come constructor is not the first method ran in class?